# As their any loading missing in loop in php?

Tags: php, loops

```
$listget=file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/list');

$list=explode('target="_',$listget);
$count=count($list);
$i='2';
for ($i=2 ; $i <= ($count-4) ; $i++) {

//function or statement here

if($my_statement===false){
  show cancel
    else{
      show second matter
         if($my_statement===false)
          {//nothing is here
            }
        else{
          show success with data}
          }
          }

else{
    show 1st matter
        if($my_statement===false)
             {
           //nothing is here}
        else{
           show success with data }
}
```

This code is working well. But when list amount is so big ( i.e more then 100 words) it just stop working after some times. Is it problem in loop or any where ?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is it's taking too long or too much memory and it's getting kicked by your server.

Comment: I wish I could help, but all you've provided here is pseudo code.  Do you have the actual code that your server is executing available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum execution time is by default 30 seconds.

You can check your actual settings with a php file

```
<?
phpinfo();
?>
```

If possible change your php.ini settings or use php cli. But be aware of server overall performance issues.

[Maximum Execution Time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)

Comment: ya, local and master value both is 30 .
Is there any chance to increase it ? or need to contact with hosting provider ?

Comment: if it is a hosting web account you probably won't be able to change it. localy you can change it in your php.ini and restart your apache or like i told use the php command line interface

Comment: is it possible  to set the file execution time for the particular file at the individual file ?

Comment: on your on server you could , on hosting i am not shure try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php never tried it on my own http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set